# Doxygen: arguments and methods with the same names

Tags: doxygen

I wanted to ask if anybody knows how to prevent doxygen producing links to methods from function arguments with the same name.
For example: in [this documentation](https://vsronin.github.io/QtModelUtilities/class_transpose_proxy_model.html), `QModelIndex buddy (const QModelIndex &index)`  the `index` argument is made into a link to the totally unrelated `index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent)` method. Do you know how to prevent this?

The links are auto-generated so I can't use the `%` in front:

My code:

In the header:

```
QModelIndex buddy(const QModelIndex &index) const override;
```

In the source:

```
/*!
\reimp
*/
QModelIndex TransposeProxyModel::buddy(const QModelIndex &index) const 
{/*some implementation*/}
```

If it matters, `\reimp` is an alias defined as `reimp=Reimplemented from base class`

Comment: As far as I know this is currently not possible, it is unfortunately that arguments are linked as well (I already intended to look at it, but the list is a bit long...). Problem still exists in the current version, 1.8.14, as well.

Comment: Thanks @albert . Do you have a link to the ticket of this know issue so we can have it as a reference for the future?

Comment: Maybe there is a ticket but I don't see it that fast (maybe I saw the problem myself and didn't like it). Feel free to creat an issue in the github issue tracker: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new

Comment: Done: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6383 . Thanks again

Comment: Related to: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/4101